# GRASS GIS v.in.ply

Tags: grass-gis, point, 3d, import

I'm trying to import a `.ply` file from MeshLab 1.33 into GRASS GIS 7.0 using `v.in.ply` addon.

But I get the error message:

`ERROR: List index must be integer, is uchar`

This appears to be referring to the faces element of the file:

```
element face 50000
property list uchar int vertex_indices
property list uchar float texcoord
```

example data:

```
3 18598 18744 18713 6 0.376742 0.28305 0.376685 0.279639 0.378521 0.280493
```

It appears to be reading the 3 references to the vertices (further up the file) as uchar not integers.

Yet they are integers and a scan of the file doesn't find anything else popping out?

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have an ASCII PLY file. I just tried:

```
GRASS 7.0.0svn (nc_spm_08_grass7):~ > v.out.ply in=geodetic_pts out=bla.ply
GRASS 7.0.0svn (nc_spm_08_grass7):~ > v.in.ply in=bla.ply out=bla
Importing 29939 vertices ...
 100%
Building topology for vector map <bla@user1>...
Registering primitives...
29939 primitives registered
29939 vertices registered
Building areas...
 100%
0 areas built
0 isles built
Attaching islands...
Attaching centroids...
 100%
Number of nodes: 0
Number of primitives: 29939
Number of points: 29939
Number of lines: 0
Number of boundaries: 0
Number of centroids: 0
Number of areas: 0
Number of isles: 0
v.in.ply complete.
GRASS 7.0.0svn (nc_spm_08_grass7):~ >
```

Looks all fine... But you write about faces: The [manual](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/addons/v.in.ply.html) states: "... v.in.ply is designed for large point clouds". Maybe the script needs to be expanded for more types.
Can you make the file or a portion available?

Comment: Removed faces from file, and worked no problem. I'd done this once before, but obviously messed up the file somewhere. Cheers for this, appreciated.

Comment: Could you prepare a minimalistic example with faces? Perhaps we could fix that then...